# Read Excel file and select specific rows and columns

Tags: r

I want to read a xls file into R and select specific columns.

For example I only want columns 1 to 10 and rows 5 - 700. I think you can do this with xlsx but I can't use that library on the network that I am using.

Is there another package that I can use? And how would I go about selecting the columns and rows that I want?

Comment: You could use `readxl`, i.e. `library(readxl); read_excel(your_file)[5:700, 1:10]`

Comment: Or with Excel style range : `read_excel(xls_file, range = "A5:J700")`

Comment: Okay thanks. with `[5:700, 1:10]` is there a way to say I was columns 1-3, not 3, 5, or 6, but I do want 7-12?

Comment: `read_excel(your_file)[5:700, c(1:3, 7:12)]`?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
 library(xlsx)
 read.xlsx("my_path\\my_file.xlsx", "sheet_name", rowIndex = 5:700, colIndex = 1:10)
```

Comment: _I think you can do this with xlsx but I can't use that library on the network that I am using_

Comment: I can't use xlsx unfortunately

Comment: Is there a way to read based on a value in cell? For instance read all rows till it is not Blank?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are unable to lead the `xlsx` package, you might want to consider `base` R and use `read.csv`. For this, save your Excel file as a csv. The explanation for how to do this can be easily found on the web. Note, csv files can still be opened as Excel.

These are the steps you need to take to only read the 2nd and 3rd column and row.

```
hd = read.csv('a.csv', header=F, nrows=1, as.is=T) # first read headers
removeCols <- c('NULL', NA, NA) #define which columns to keep/remove

df <- read.csv('a.csv', skip=2, header=F, colClasses=removeCols) #skip says which rows not to read
colnames(df) <- hd[is.na(removeCols)]

df

  two three
1   5     8
2   6     9
```

This is the example data I used.

```
a <- data.frame(one=1:3, two=4:6, three=7:9)
write.csv(a, 'a.csv', row.names=F)
read.csv('a.csv')

  one two three
1   1   4     7
2   2   5     8
3   3   6     9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `read_excel()` from the `readxl` package, which lets you specify a range using Excel's own range syntax:

```r
readxl::read_excel(filePath, sheet = "sheet_name", range = "A1:J100")
```

`xlsx` doesn't work on some networks because it requires Java, but `readxl` has no such requirement.