# How to pick two particular columns from .xlsx file using 'readxl' package?

Tags: r, readxl

I have a .xlsx file that contains 28 columns. Out of these, I wish to select only the column numbers 3 ("Salesperson") and 28 ("Customer ID").
I tried following two code but none of them seems to work. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here:

```
read_xlsx("Active List till 7 Feb .xlsx",sheet = "Raw data",col_names = c("Salesperson","Customer ID"))
```

**OR**

```
read_xlsx("Active List till 7 Feb .xlsx",sheet = "Raw data",col_names = c(3,28))
```

And I am getting following error when using the first code

```
Error: Sheet 4 has 28 columns (28 unskipped), but `col_names` has length 2
```

In the second code, I am getting all columns from 3 to 28 and not just 3 and 28.

I know I can select specific columns later using `select()` but I wanted to know how do I specify this directly into the `read_xlsx()` function. Also let me know if there's a better way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Read excel file and select specific rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930684/r-read-excel-file-and-select-specific-rows-and-columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for that

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_201")
library(xlsx)
read.xlsx("Active List till 7 Feb .xlsx", sheetName = "Raw data", colIndex = c(3,28))
```

## or

Solution using `openxlsx` package

```
library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx("Active List till 7 Feb .xlsx", sheet = "Raw data", cols = c(3,28))
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way how I could achieve this using the `read_xlsx` function from `readxl` package

Comment: I am afraid that is possible with `readxl` package. Is it absolutely necessary to do it with `readxl`?

Comment: No, actually I wanted to know what am I doing wrong in my code. I am able to get the job done even if I use `select()` after `read_xlsx()`. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: It is not possible with `read_xlsx()` what I can get from its help.